# How do I bind XAML Label with TapGestureRecognizer using MVVM?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uitapgesturerecognizer, reactiveui

I am trying to simulate a XAML button with the use of a `Frame` (for border and background) and a `Label` (for button text).  However, I need to add a `TapGestureRecognizer` for the simulated button to work when clicked.  I am trying to do this within the confines of using ReactiveUI and MVVM, but can't seem to hook up the bindings properly.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2017/10/01/Create-Responsive.aspx?Page=2), which sets up the bindings in the XAML code behind as follows:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPageBase<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
        {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Username, c => c.UsernameEntry.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);

            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Password, c => c.PasswordEntry.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);

            //this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.LoginCommand, x => x.LoginButton.LoginCommand)
            //    .DisposeWith(disposables);

            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.LoginCommand, x => x.SimulatedLoginButton.TapGestureCommandGoesHere)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);

            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.IsLoading, x => x.LoginActivityIndicator.IsRunning)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
    }
```

I've commented out the `Button` binding (above) and inserted the simulated `Button` code (which doesn't compile of course).  The problem is the simulated Button (Frame) doesn't have a `button.Command`, and I'm not sure how to add the tapgesture command so that it's recognized.

I have seen/tried XAML with `Frame.TapGestureRecognizer` tag, but wasn't able to get the binding to work with XAML using this method.

Any ideas how I can get this working with an MVVM implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your XAML you have to have something like this:

```
<Frame>
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
     <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="Gesture" />
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```

And in your code behind:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.LoginCommand, x => x.Gesture.Command)
        .DisposeWith(disposables);
```

I hope this helps you